# One class SVM and centered data

Tags: machine-learning, svm, one-class, novelty-detection

I understand that the one class SVM try to separate the normal training data point from the origin.

My guess is that, if we centered the data in a normalisation step, the OCSMV will works poorly since the data will be artificially closed to the origin.

This is, in my opinion, still valid with a polynomial kernel since this kernel conserve the centerness of the data around the origin.

**So should we not centered the data if using a kernel that conserve the proximity of the data to the origin (linear, polynomial, ...) ?**

*without kernel*

[image]

*with polynomial kernel*

[image]